# why can Javascript function can update original property of object from outside but cannot update original variable

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables

```
    let variable1="hello";
function func1(variable){
    variable="hello hello";
}
func1(variable1);
console.log("after function: "+variable1);

let object1={
    property1:"hello2"
}
function func2(obj){
    obj.property="hello object";
}
func2(object1);
console.log("after function:" +object1.property);
```

I have this code,
the first console.log() returns

```
hello
```

but second console.log() returns

```
hello object
```

So I understood javascript cannot change and update variable but it can change and update property of object.
But why and how?

Comment: Probably also relevant: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431)

Comment: @VLAZ thank you, I think the link you sent me will help me much to be a better web developer